# Python / XML: lxml insert not functioning in a loop with deepcopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, elementtree

I'm attempting to use lxml + itertools to insert deepcopies of a prior element. No matter what I seem to do I can only get the new element to insert once.

In the example, you can see I'm attempting to insert 5 times (in practice this is a variable, but you know - keep it simple).

The actual XML I have is not too complex, but does have a lot of elements, so I'll supply a smaller sample version.

What am I missing here? Do I need to somehow write updates to root or tree after doing root.insert(insertPosition newWx) before continuing the loop?

```
from lxml import etree
import copy
import itertools

tree = etree.parse('myfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Find element to copy 
originalWx = tree.find("Weather")

insertPosition = int(tree.xpath('count(//Weather[last()]/preceding-sibling::*)')+1)
print("Next position for <Weather> is: " + str(insertPosition))

# Create a copy
newWx = copy.deepcopy(originalWx)

for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 5):
    root.insert(insertPosition, newWx)
    insertPosition = insertPosition + 1
```

Starting XML:

```
<ProjectDataSet>
  <Project>
    <Id>0.1.2</Id>
    <Project_Name>Weather Stream Sample</Project_Name>
    <End_Time>2021-06-30T13:00:00+10:00</End_Time>
    <Comments>Project Comments</Comments>
  </Project>
  <Thing>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Project_Id>492</Project_Id>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Merged_By>0</Merged_By>
    <Merged>0001-01-01T00:00:00+10:00</Merged>
    <Comments/>
  </Thing>
  <Detail>
    <Order_Id>1</Order_Id>
    <X>1095935</X>
    <Y>6999365</Y>
  </Detail>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather_Entry>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Weather_Time>2021-06-29T10:00:00+10:00</Weather_Time>
    <Temperature>28</Temperature>
    <Rel_Humidity>20</Rel_Humidity>
    <Wind_Speed>15.4</Wind_Speed>
  </Weather_Entry>
  <Weather_Entry>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Weather_Time>2021-06-29T11:00:00+10:00</Weather_Time>
    <Temperature>29</Temperature>
    <Rel_Humidity>24</Rel_Humidity>
    <Wind_Speed>12.4</Wind_Speed>
  </Weather_Entry>
  <Setting>
    <stuff>True</stuff>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
    <stuff2>False</stuff2>
  </Setting>
<ProjectDataSet>
```

What I get:

```
<ProjectDataSet>
  <Project>
    <Id>0.1.2</Id>
    <Project_Name>Weather Stream Sample</Project_Name>
    <End_Time>2021-06-30T13:00:00+10:00</End_Time>
    <Comments>Project Comments</Comments>
  </Project>
  <Thing>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Project_Id>492</Project_Id>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Merged_By>0</Merged_By>
    <Merged>0001-01-01T00:00:00+10:00</Merged>
    <Comments/>
  </Thing>
  <Detail>
    <Order_Id>1</Order_Id>
    <X>1095935</X>
    <Y>6999365</Y>
  </Detail>

*** Added break for clarity ***

  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>



  <Weather_Entry>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Weather_Time>2021-06-29T10:00:00+10:00</Weather_Time>
    <Temperature>28</Temperature>
    <Rel_Humidity>20</Rel_Humidity>
    <Wind_Speed>15.4</Wind_Speed>
  </Weather_Entry>
  <Weather_Entry>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Weather_Time>2021-06-29T11:00:00+10:00</Weather_Time>
    <Temperature>29</Temperature>
    <Rel_Humidity>24</Rel_Humidity>
    <Wind_Speed>12.4</Wind_Speed>
  </Weather_Entry>
  <Setting>
    <stuff>True</stuff>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
    <stuff2>False</stuff2>
  </Setting>
<ProjectDataSet>
```

What I'm expecting to get:

```
<ProjectDataSet>
  <Project>
    <Id>0.1.2</Id>
    <Project_Name>Weather Stream Sample</Project_Name>
    <End_Time>2021-06-30T13:00:00+10:00</End_Time>
    <Comments>Project Comments</Comments>
  </Project>
  <Thing>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Project_Id>492</Project_Id>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Merged_By>0</Merged_By>
    <Merged>0001-01-01T00:00:00+10:00</Merged>
    <Comments/>
  </Thing>
  <Detail>
    <Order_Id>1</Order_Id>
    <X>1095935</X>
    <Y>6999365</Y>
  </Detail>

*** Added break for clarity ***

  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>
  <Weather>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Weather_Name>Original Weather</Weather_Name>
    <Comments>Original Weather</Comments>
    <Latitude>-27</Latitude>
    <Longitude>153</Longitude>
  </Weather>



  <Weather_Entry>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Weather_Time>2021-06-29T10:00:00+10:00</Weather_Time>
    <Temperature>28</Temperature>
    <Rel_Humidity>20</Rel_Humidity>
    <Wind_Speed>15.4</Wind_Speed>
  </Weather_Entry>
  <Weather_Entry>
    <Weather_Id>2</Weather_Id>
    <Weather_Time>2021-06-29T11:00:00+10:00</Weather_Time>
    <Temperature>29</Temperature>
    <Rel_Humidity>24</Rel_Humidity>
    <Wind_Speed>12.4</Wind_Speed>
  </Weather_Entry>
  <Setting>
    <stuff>True</stuff>
  </Setting>
  <Setting>
    <stuff2>False</stuff2>
  </Setting>
<ProjectDataSet>
```

Comment: If you want to add five copies of originalWx, you'll need to make five copies of it. You're only making one copy, and you can't add the same subtree more than once.

Comment: That's a pain. Thanks for the info. IF you add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct. If you happen to have a snippet of code that you know to work well, that would be good - otherwise I'll add something here once I have it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add five copies of `originalWx`,  you'll need to make five copies of it. You're only making one copy, and you can't add the same subtree more than once.

So remove

```
newWx = copy.deepcopy(originalWx)
```

and then change the loop to

```
root.insert(insertPosition, copy.deepcopy(originalWx))
```

so that each loop inserts a new copy.

In this regard, the `lxml.etree` API is very similar to the JavaScript DOM implementation. Every element in the XML tree has a single parent (which you can discover using the `parent()` method) which means that when you insert an element into the tree as a child of some node, it can no longer be the child of another node. In other words, it will be moved. This is noted in the [compatibility with ElementTree section of the lxml.etree documentation](https://lxml.de/compatibility.html). (It's the fourth bullet point. I couldn't find a more accurate link.)